# How to Carry Over Validation onto Newly Added Table Rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

So I have a table with two separate buttons, Edit and Deactivate. I was able to use a bind function on the deactivate and edit in order to get the button to work when I added rows. I also have validation for most of the fields. The validation works perfectly on the original rows, but does not work on any rows that are added by the user. How can I fix this?

HTML/PHP:

```
<table id="html_master">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td>Buyer ID</td>
    <td>POC Name</td>
    <td>POC Email</td>
    <td>POC Phone</td>
    <td>Edit/Delete</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="mr_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit">
        <input type="button" class="deactivate" name="deactivate" value="Deactivate"></td>
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
</tbody>
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('html_master')">
</table>

<input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('html_master')">

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
// ----- Deactivate Row -----

function bindDeactivate() {
  $('#html_master').on("click",".deactivate",function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $tr = $this.closest('tr');
    var action = $tr.hasClass('deactivated') ? 'activate' : 'deactivate';

    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to ' + action + ' this entry?')) {
      $tr.toggleClass('deactivated');
      $this.val(function(i, t) {
        return t == 'Deactivate' ? 'Activate' : 'Deactivate';
      });
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Bind the deactivate button click to the function
    bindDeactivate();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Bind the edit button click to the function
    bindEdit();
});

// ----- Add Row -----

function addRow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = rowCount;

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell2.appendChild(element2);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    element3.type = "text";
    element3.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell3.appendChild(element3);

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var element4 = document.createElement("input");
    element4.type = "text";
    element4.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell4.appendChild(element4);

    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var element5 = document.createElement("input");
    element5.type = "text";
    element5.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell5.appendChild(element5);

    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    var element6 = document.createElement("input");
    element6.type = "text";
    element6.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell6.appendChild(element6);

    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
    var element7 = document.createElement("input");
    var element8 = document.createElement("input");
    element7.type = "button";
    element8.type = "button";
    element7.name="edit";
    element8.name="deactivate";

    var setClass = document.createAttribute("class");
    setClass.value = "edit";
    element7.setAttributeNode(setClass);

    var setClass1 = document.createAttribute("class");
    setClass1.value = "deactivate";
    element8.setAttributeNode(setClass1);

    element7.attr="class";
    element8.attr="class";
    element7.value="Edit";
    element8.value="Deactivate";
    cell7.appendChild(element7);
    cell7.appendChild(element8);

    // Bind this new deactivate button click to the function
    $('#html_master').off("click",'.deactivate');
    bindDeactivate();

    // Bind this new deactivate button click to the function
    $('#html_master').off("click",'.edit');
    bindEdit();
}




function bindEdit() {
    $('#html_master').on("click",".edit",function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').not('.mr_id').filter(function() {
        return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
    });
    if ($this.val() === 'Edit') {
        $this.val('Save');
        tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
    } else {
        var isValid = true;
        var errors = '';
        $('#myDialogBox').empty();
        tds.each(function(){
             var type = $(this).attr('class');
             var value = $(this).text();
             switch(type){
                 case "buyer_id":
                     if(!$.isNumeric(value)){
                         isValid = false;
                         errors += "Please enter a valid Buyer ID\n";
                      }
                     break;
                case "poc_n":
                    if(value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/)){
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        isValid = false;
                        errors += "Please enter a valid Name\n";
                    }
                    break;
                case "poc_e":
                    if(value == value.match(/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/)){
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        isValid = false;
                        errors += "Please enter a valid Email\n";
                    }
                    break;
                case "poc_p":
                    if(value == value.match('^[0-9 ()+/-]{10,}$')){
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        isValid = false;
                        errors += "Please enter a valid Phone Number\n";    
                    }
                    break;
             }
        })
        if(isValid){
            $this.val('Edit');              // Modifed
            tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
        }else{
            alert(errors);
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: whereis "The validation works perfectly on the original rows" in your question? How do you validate?

Comment: my validation is in a switch statement in the javascript

Comment: it would be nice if when a row is added, the "save" button displays first instead of the "edit" button...it would make the most sense because your adding info then you want to hit save....but thats second priority right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For newly created dom elements your approach to delegation is complicated. I suggest you to simplify it:

```
$(document).on("click", "#html_master .deactivate", function () {
$(document).on("click", "#html_master .edit", function () {
```

This will avoid confusion and reduce line numbers: you do not need to bind -- unbind -- bind event.

The problem you are experiencing with the validation is related on how you ceate the new elements. They need the class you are looking for in the validation. So in your ***function addRow(tableID) {***  for each new element you need to add the class like:

```
element2.className = 'mr_name';
```

So the snippet is:

```js
// ----- Deactivate/Activate Row -----

$(document).on("click", "#html_master .deactivate", function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $tr = $this.closest('tr');
  var action = $tr.hasClass('deactivated') ? 'activate' : 'deactivate';

  // ------ Confirmation box in order to deactivate/activate row -----
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to ' + action + ' this entry?')) {
    $tr.toggleClass('deactivated');
    $this.val(function (i, t) {
      return t == 'Deactivate' ? 'Activate' : 'Deactivate';
    });
  }
});

// ----- Edit Row -----

$(document).on("click", "#html_master .edit", function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').not('.mr_id').filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
  });
  if ($this.val() === 'Edit') {
    $this.val('Save');
    tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
  } else {
    var isValid = true;
    var errors = '';
    $('#myDialogBox').empty();
    // changed from here.......
    var elements = tds;
    if (tds.find('input').length > 0) {
      elements = tds.find('input');
    }
    elements.each(function (index, element) {
      var type = $(this).attr('class');
      var value = (element.tagName == 'INPUT') ? $(this).val() : $(this).text();
      // changed from here....... to here
      // ----- Switch statement that provides validation -----
      switch (type) {
        case "buyer_id":
          if (!$.isNumeric(value)) {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Buyer ID\n";
          }
          break;
        case "poc_n":
          if (value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/)) {
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Name\n";
          }
          break;
        case "poc_e":
          if (value == value.match(/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/)) {
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Email\n";
          }
          break;
        case "poc_p":
          if (value == value.match('^[0-9 ()+/-]{10,}$')) {
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Phone Number\n";
          }
          break;
      }
    })
    if (isValid) {
      $this.val('Edit');
      tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
    } else {
      alert(errors);
    }
  }
});


// ----- Add Row -----

function addRow(tableID) {

  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell1.innerHTML = rowCount;
  cell1.className = 'mr_id';

  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var element2 = document.createElement("input");
  element2.type = "text";
  element2.name = "txtbox[]";
  element2.className = 'mr_name';
  cell2.appendChild(element2);

  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var element3 = document.createElement("input");
  element3.type = "text";
  element3.name = "txtbox[]";
  element3.className = 'buyer_id';
  cell3.appendChild(element3);

  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var element4 = document.createElement("input");
  element4.type = "text";
  element4.name = "txtbox[]";
  element4.className = 'poc_n';
  cell4.appendChild(element4);

  var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  var element5 = document.createElement("input");
  element5.type = "text";
  element5.name = "txtbox[]";
  element5.className = 'poc_e';
  cell5.appendChild(element5);

  var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
  var element6 = document.createElement("input");
  element6.type = "text";
  element6.name = "txtbox[]";
  element6.className = 'poc_p';
  cell6.appendChild(element6);

  var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
  var element7 = document.createElement("input");
  var element8 = document.createElement("input");
  element7.type = "button";
  element8.type = "button";
  element7.name = "edit";
  element8.name = "deactivate";

  var setClass = document.createAttribute("class");
  setClass.value = "edit";
  element7.setAttributeNode(setClass);

  var setClass1 = document.createAttribute("class");
  setClass1.value = "deactivate";
  element8.setAttributeNode(setClass1);

  element7.attr = "class";
  element8.attr = "class";
  element7.value = "Save";
  element8.value = "Deactivate";
  cell7.appendChild(element7);
  cell7.appendChild(element8);
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
}

thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.deactivated {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="html_master">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Vendor</td>
        <td>Buyer ID</td>
        <td>POC Name</td>
        <td>POC Email</td>
        <td>POC Phone</td>
        <td>Edit/Delete</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="mr_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>
        <td class="poc_e" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit">
            <input type="button" class="deactivate" name="deactivate" value="Deactivate"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
  }
 ?>
    </tbody>
    <br>
    <input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('html_master')">
</table>

<input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('html_master')">
```

Comment: this is great that the additional rows now have validation...however, all of the original rows do not have any validation anymore

Comment: Works great, thank you!! Is there a way so that when I add a row, it displays Save with the validation instead of clicking edit first?? It would just make more sense...although I know this is kind of separate from my original question.

Comment: Also, what did you change just so I can know for future purposes?

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to get that easily...thanks again for the help!

Comment: Actually after further testing, theres is a problem...there is validation, however, when I enter the new information and hit save, the validation dialog box pops up and says i need to enter the correct info when I actually have! Why is this?

Comment: use this...http://codepen.io/Rataiczak24/pen/wzpJop notice that if you enter a phone number in the original row, there is no error when saving...however if you enter a phone number in the added row then when you click save, it still says i need a phone number...so i guess its not recognizing the input

Comment: @Rataiczak24 Snippet updated. See the javascript code for: // changed from here....... to here. The problem was: a div is accessed by text() while a textbox with val().  Sorry. Let me know if you have other problems.

Comment: Yes, that works thank you. Is there a way to make it so that the rows are exactly like the other rows...in that there is no textbox and i can just edit it inline? And so that it can't be edited after i save it unless i click edit again like all the other rows?